# Rename [pes] tags → [pro-evolution-soccer]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

There are a number of tags for the [Pro Evolution Soccer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_Evolution_Soccer) series that use the abbrevation "pes" in their tag name. Now that we have a 35 character tag limit, let's expand those:

- [pes-2009](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pes-2009) → [pro-evolution-soccer-2009](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-2009)
- [pes-2010](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pes-2010) → [pro-evolution-soccer-2010](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-2010)
- [pes-2011](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pes-2011) → [pro-evolution-soccer-2011](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-2011)
- [pes-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pes-2012) → [pro-evolution-soccer-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-2012)
- [pes-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pes-2013) → [pro-evolution-soccer-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-2013)
- [pes-2014](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pes-2014) → [pro-evolution-soccer-2014](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-2014)
- [pes-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pes-2015) → [pro-evolution-soccer-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-2015)
- [pes-2016](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pes-2016) → [pro-evolution-soccer-2016](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-2016)

There is also [pro-evolution-soccer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer) already, but it doesn't have a clear usage and is used for three different games. Perhaps we should just delete that one?

Note that while the games are commonly referred to as *PES 20xx*, Wikipedia and most retailers and review sites refer to each game as *Pro Evolution Soccer 20xx*. Therefore, I think that the longer versions are what we want, but the shorter ones should be kept as synonyms.

Comment: Isn't it sold as PES? I know it stands for something, but it seems like it would be harder to find if you use this.

Comment: @TankorSmash [Amazon's page](https://smile.amazon.com/Pro-Evolution-Soccer-2018-PlayStation-Standard/dp/B071FK2WRT/) has it as "Pro Evolution Soccer 2018", as does [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_Evolution_Soccer_2018). The cover art is a little ambiguous (I see it as "PES 2018: Pro Evolution Soccer"), but given that multiple places write out the title as "Pro Evolution Soccer", I think that's what we should go with. If you're concerned about search engines, Google gets pretty much the same results with `pes 2018` and `pro evolution soccer 2018`, due to acronym expansion.

Comment: Fair enough, despite the box art, a popular vendor has it listed in the longer form. Still feels like you wouldn't want to do the same for NHL, FIFA or any other sports game though.

Comment: @TankorSmash It's also spelled that way on [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/592580/Pro_Evolution_Soccer_2018/), [Wal-Mart](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Pro-Evo-Soccer-2018-for-PlayStation-4/55855178), [Gamespot](https://www.gamespot.com/pro-evolution-soccer-2018/), and [Metacritic](http://www.metacritic.com/game/playstation-4/pro-evolution-soccer-2018). The only exception I found was [Best Buy](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/pes-2018-pro-evolution-soccer-playstation-4/5925210.p?skuId=5925210) (it's "PES 2018: Pro Evolution Soccer"). I think we should defer to the majority, and Wikipedia.

Comment: @TankorSmash Keeping a synonym would make sense though, that way someone who types `pes-2018` into the tag field would still find it.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering if this is a useful change. Besides being the full name of it, do more people refer to it as Pro Evolution Soccer, in spoken word or written down? I don't see the value, even if the data so far suggests calling it Pro Evolution Soccer is well known.

Comment: Actually, having it written out in full helps people unfamiliar with the acronym, so I think there is value in this.

Comment: @TankorSmash I think that we need one of the two tags to be the "parent" tag and the other to be a synonym. As is, users who type `pro-evolution-soccer` won't find any tags, and they might not think to type the acronym. If we need to pick one tag to be the parent and the other to be the synonym, I would prefer the correct name of the game to be the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are done, but there was some cleanup required of the questions in the [pro-evolution-soccer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer) tag as they were all over the place, so here's what I changed:

- Created [pro-evolution-soccer-2017](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-2017) tag (and shorthand 'PES' synonym)
- Created [pro-evolution-soccer-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-5) tag & synonyms (See the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_Evolution_Soccer_5) article for an explanation on the below tag synonyms)
- Renamed [pro-evolution-soccer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer) to [pro-evolution-soccer-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-series), and created a shorthand [pes-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pes-series) synonym.
- Updated [pro-evolution-soccer-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-series) Excerpt & Wiki to match the tag's new function.
- Created [pro-evolution-soccer-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-5)'s Excerpt & Wiki.

---

Here are the final results:

- [pes-2009](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pes-2009) → [pro-evolution-soccer-2009](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-2009)
- [pes-2010](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pes-2010) → [pro-evolution-soccer-2010](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-2010)
- [pes-2011](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pes-2011) → [pro-evolution-soccer-2011](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-2011)
- [pes-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pes-2012) → [pro-evolution-soccer-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-2012)
- [pes-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pes-2013) → [pro-evolution-soccer-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-2013)
- [pes-2014](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pes-2014) → [pro-evolution-soccer-2014](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-2014)
- [pes-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pes-2015) → [pro-evolution-soccer-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-2015)
- [pes-2016](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pes-2016) → [pro-evolution-soccer-2016](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-2016)
- [pes-2017](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pes-2017) → [pro-evolution-soccer-2017](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-2017)
- [pes-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pes-series) → [pro-evolution-soccer-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-series)
- [pes-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pes-5), [world-soccer-winning-eleven-9](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-soccer-winning-eleven-9), [winning-eleven-9-international](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winning-eleven-9-international) → [pro-evolution-soccer-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer-5)

Comment: Thanks for your hard work! Is there a need for a series-wide [pro-evolution-soccer] tag? I didn't think that we had any questions about multiple games, so if there are no questions, won't the tag get purged?

Comment: After cleanup into the individual game tags we had two questions left that refer to multiple games in the series, it seemed fitting to use the series tags for those.